Why are elements in a SwiftUI form horizontally aligned when I change the style of my Toggle element?
I try doing a test project for MacOS because I'm currently learning Swift/SwiftUI and encountered a problem with forms and toggle elements. When I add a toggle element as it is everything looks like it should, but as soon as I add the .switch Style, every new "line" of the forms align itself with the start of the Switch.
I tried rapping the stuff in Groups, VStacks and stuff like that but nothing really helped.
Here is my Code:
import SwiftUI
import Foundation`

let serverNameList = ["HTTP Server", "Test", "IOT", "Messenger"]

// view
struct ContentView: View {
    // state variables
    @State private var companiesExpanded = true
    @State private var isHTTPServerOn = true
    
    // body
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            var serverImage = Image(systemName: "globe")
                .padding(10.0)
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            
            NavigationSplitView {
                DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: $companiesExpanded) {
                    
                    ForEach(serverNameList, id: \.self) { serverName in
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Destination")) {
                            Label {
                                Text(serverName)
                            } icon: {
                                Image(systemName: "server.rack")
                                    .foregroundStyle(Color.blue)
                            }
                                .frame(minWidth: 100,
                                       idealWidth: 200,
                                       maxWidth: 300,
                                       alignment: .leading)
                                .padding(5)
                        }
                            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                            .navigationSubtitle("Subtitle")
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Server")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                    .frame(minWidth: 120,
                           idealWidth: 180,
                           maxWidth: 350,
                           minHeight: 120,
                           idealHeight: 300,
                           alignment: .top)
                Spacer()
            } detail: {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    HStack(alignment: .top) {
                        
                        // form 1
                        Form {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Name")
                                    .frame(minWidth: 100,
                                           idealWidth: 100,
                                           maxWidth: 150,
                                           minHeight: 25,
                                           idealHeight: 30,
                                           maxHeight: 40,
                                           alignment: .leading)
                                Text("HTTP Server")
                                    .frame(minWidth: 120,
                                           idealWidth: 200,
                                           maxWidth: 220,
                                           minHeight: 25,
                                           idealHeight: 30,
                                           maxHeight: 40,
                                           alignment: .trailing)
                            }
                            Divider()
                            HStack {
                                Text("Version")
                                    .frame(minWidth: 100,
                                           idealWidth: 100,
                                           maxWidth: 150,
                                           minHeight: 25,
                                           idealHeight: 30,
                                           maxHeight: 40,
                                           alignment: .leading)
                                Text("0.13.2")
                                    .frame(minWidth: 120,
                                           idealWidth: 200,
                                           maxWidth: 220,
                                           minHeight: 25,
                                           idealHeight: 30,
                                           maxHeight: 40,
                                           alignment: .trailing)
                            }
                            Divider()
                            HStack {
                                Text("Status")
                                    .frame(minWidth: 100,
                                           idealWidth: 100,
                                           maxWidth: 150,
                                           minHeight: 25,
                                           idealHeight: 30,
                                           maxHeight: 40,
                                           alignment: .leading)
                                HStack {
                                    Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                                        .foregroundStyle(Color.green)
                                        .frame(width: 8,
                                               height: 8,
                                               alignment: .center)
                                    Text("ONLINE")
                                }
                                    .frame(minWidth: 120,
                                           idealWidth: 200,
                                           maxWidth: 220,
                                           minHeight: 25,
                                           idealHeight: 30,
                                           maxHeight: 40,
                                           alignment: .trailing)
                            }
                            Divider()
                            HStack {
                                Text("Domain")
                                    .frame(minWidth: 100,
                                           idealWidth: 100,
                                           maxWidth: 150,
                                           minHeight: 25,
                                           idealHeight: 30,
                                           maxHeight: 40,
                                           alignment: .leading)
                                Text("IPv4")
                                    .frame(minWidth: 120,
                                           idealWidth: 200,
                                           maxWidth: 220,
                                           minHeight: 25,
                                           idealHeight: 30,
                                           maxHeight: 40,
                                           alignment: .trailing)
                            }
                            Divider()
                            HStack {
                                Text("Connections")
                                    .frame(minWidth: 100,
                                           idealWidth: 100,
                                           maxWidth: 150,
                                           minHeight: 25,
                                           idealHeight: 30,
                                           maxHeight: 40,
                                           alignment: .leading)
                                Text("6")
                                    .frame(minWidth: 120,
                                           idealWidth: 200,
                                           maxWidth: 220,
                                           minHeight: 25,
                                           idealHeight: 30,
                                           maxHeight: 40,
                                           alignment: .trailing)
                            }
                            Divider()
                            HStack {
                                Text("Owner")
                                    .frame(minWidth: 100,
                                           idealWidth: 100,
                                           maxWidth: 150,
                                           minHeight: 25,
                                           idealHeight: 30,
                                           maxHeight: 40,
                                           alignment: .leading)
                                Text("Max Mustermann")
                                    .frame(minWidth: 120,
                                           idealWidth: 200,
                                           maxWidth: 220,
                                           minHeight: 25,
                                           idealHeight: 30,
                                           maxHeight: 40,
                                           alignment: .trailing)
                            }
                        }
                            .padding(10)
                            .frame(minWidth: 260,
                                   idealWidth: 300,
                                   maxWidth: 370,
                                   minHeight: 210,
                                   idealHeight: 240,
                                   maxHeight: 300,
                                   alignment: .topLeading)
                            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                                .stroke(Color.black.opacity(0.1),
                                        lineWidth: 1))
                        
                        // form 2
                        Form {
                            HStack {
                                Text(isHTTPServerOn ? "Turn off" : "Turn on")
                                Toggle("", isOn: $isHTTPServerOn)
                                    .toggleStyle(.switch)
                                    .frame(minWidth: 120,
                                           idealWidth: 200,
                                           maxWidth: 220,
                                           minHeight: 25,
                                           idealHeight: 30,
                                           maxHeight: 40,
                                           alignment: .trailing)
                            }
                            Divider()
                            HStack {
                                Text("Version")
                                    .frame(minWidth: 100,
                                           idealWidth: 100,
                                           maxWidth: 150,
                                           minHeight: 25,
                                           idealHeight: 30,
                                           maxHeight: 40,
                                           alignment: .leading)
                                Text("0.13.2")
                                    .frame(minWidth: 120,
                                           idealWidth: 200,
                                           maxWidth: 220,
                                           minHeight: 25,
                                           idealHeight: 30,
                                           maxHeight: 40,
                                           alignment: .trailing)
                            }
                            Divider()
                            HStack {
                                Text("Status")
                                    .frame(minWidth: 100,
                                           idealWidth: 100,
                                           maxWidth: 150,
                                           minHeight: 25,
                                           idealHeight: 30,
                                           maxHeight: 40,
                                           alignment: .leading)
                                HStack {
                                    Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                                        .foregroundStyle(Color.green)
                                        .frame(width: 8,
                                               height: 8,
                                               alignment: .center)
                                    Text("ONLINE")
                                }
                                    .frame(minWidth: 120,
                                           idealWidth: 200,
                                           maxWidth: 220,
                                           minHeight: 25,
                                           idealHeight: 30,
                                           maxHeight: 40,
                                           alignment: .trailing)
                            }
                            Divider()
                            HStack {
                                Text("Domain")
                                    .frame(minWidth: 100,
                                           idealWidth: 100,
                                           maxWidth: 150,
                                           minHeight: 25,
                                           idealHeight: 30,
                                           maxHeight: 40,
                                           alignment: .leading)
                                Text("IPv4")
                                    .frame(minWidth: 120,
                                           idealWidth: 200,
                                           maxWidth: 220,
                                           minHeight: 25,
                                           idealHeight: 30,
                                           maxHeight: 40,
                                           alignment: .trailing)
                            }
                            Divider()
                            HStack {
                                Text("Connections")
                                    .frame(minWidth: 100,
                                           idealWidth: 100,
                                           maxWidth: 150,
                                           minHeight: 25,
                                           idealHeight: 30,
                                           maxHeight: 40,
                                           alignment: .leading)
                                Text("6")
                                    .frame(minWidth: 120,
                                           idealWidth: 200,
                                           maxWidth: 220,
                                           minHeight: 25,
                                           idealHeight: 30,
                                           maxHeight: 40,
                                           alignment: .trailing)
                            }
                            Divider()
                            HStack {
                                Text("Owner")
                                    .frame(minWidth: 100,
                                           idealWidth: 100,
                                           maxWidth: 150,
                                           minHeight: 25,
                                           idealHeight: 30,
                                           maxHeight: 40,
                                           alignment: .leading)
                                Text("Max Mustermann")
                                    .frame(minWidth: 120,
                                           idealWidth: 200,
                                           maxWidth: 220,
                                           minHeight: 25,
                                           idealHeight: 30,
                                           maxHeight: 40,
                                           alignment: .trailing)
                            }
                        }
                            .padding(10)
                            .frame(minWidth: 260,
                                   idealWidth: 300,
                                   maxWidth: 370,
                                   minHeight: 210,
                                   idealHeight: 240,
                                   maxHeight: 300,
                                   alignment: .topLeading)
                            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                                .stroke(Color.black.opacity(0.1),
                                        lineWidth: 1))
                    }
                }
                    .padding(1)
                    .frame(minWidth: 4 * 10 + 220 + 2,
                           idealWidth: 3*(300+2),
                           maxWidth: .infinity,
                           minHeight: 1*(210+2),
                           idealHeight: 3*(240+2),
                           maxHeight: .infinity,
                           alignment: .topLeading)
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

Here is a screenshot of how it roughly should look (here the toogle doesn't have the .switch style):

And here how it acutally looks:

Thanks everyone in advance!
EDIT:
I also added a red border for viewing. Here is thescreenshot:


So because a couple people red the post but didn't answered I guess this is a bug. For now i use the toggle without the .switch but would be very pleased if anyone know what to do and post it.

I found who's guilty here. It's the Form. When I change it to VStack, it doesn't bug out.

@Radioactive's comment is right. After I changed the form into a VStack, everthing looks like it should. Nonetheless it's weird that the toggle in the form behaves in such a way.
