Incorrect .sheet behaviour?
I want to show a Form{} from a .sheet, with a .medium .presentationDetent. But when I have a TextField in the Form the sheet always shows as .large. Is it me, or is this some kind of bug?
My code:
struct ListViewTriggerSheet: View {
    private var dataModel = ["Inner One",
            "Inner Two", "Inner Three", "Inner Four", "Inner Five", "Inner Six"]
    
    @State private var shouldPresentSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40.00), spacing: 10),
                            GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40.00), spacing: 10)]) {
            ForEach(dataModel, id: \.self) { innerItem in
                InnerListItemView(data: innerItem)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        shouldPresentSheet = true
                    }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $shouldPresentSheet) {
            } content: {
                ListViewSheetView(textString: "Foo")
                    .presentationDetents([.medium])
            }
        }
    }
}

struct InnerListItemView : View {
    @State var data: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(data)
    }
}

struct ListViewSheetView : View {
    @State var textString: String
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text(textString)
            // Remove TextField() below and the .sheet behaves differently
            TextField("Beskrivning", text: $textString)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ListViewTriggerSheet()
}

If I remove the TextField from ListViewSheetView the .sheet is displayed correctly, but with it in, or if I remove the Form {} .medium is used. So it seems the presence of TextField in the Form {} triggers it. Is it a bug?

Yea forms are a bit buggy. Another example of buggyness: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78297213/why-are-elements-in-a-swiftui-form-horizontally-aligned-when-i-change-the-style

You should use vstack insted of form

But I want the functionality of Form {}...

State should always be private

Does this still happen if you set a custom TextFieldStyle?

I haven't tried that, but is it a likely workaround? Not that bugs are rational... :-)

State should be private - yes! But this was just some quick poc code... Doesn't make a difference for the .sheet problem.
